# Swift 3 to 4 - Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'handleScreenTap(sender:)' that is not exposed to Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code..

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, , Alertable {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleScreenTap(sender:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

And this is the error:

```
Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'handleScreenTap(sender:)' that is not exposed to Objective-C
```

I tried adding **@objc** to override func viewDidLoad():

```
@objc override func viewDidLoad() {
```

But the same error continues.

How can I fix this?

Comment: No, it means add `@objc` to `handleScreenTap(sender:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@objc` to the function in the selector

like this:

```
@objc func handleScreenTap(sender:Any) {
}
```